# Segmentation fault when using strcat (minimal example)

Tags: c

I want to add "$" to the end of the string, I've seen that I can use `strcat()` and I wrote the following code:

```
char *word = "1000";
const char *dollar = "$";
strcat(word,dollar);
printf("%s", word);
```

It compiles, but when I run the little program I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.
Where is the error?

I know that strcat is:
`char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);`

Comment: @H2CO3 but if I didn't understand I have a permission to ask, righ?

Comment: @H2CO3 How do you know that I didn't google it?

Comment: Deduction using logic and experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where is the error?

You mean where **are** the **errors**, right?

The first one is that string literals are readonly. You can't just `strcat()` onto a string constant like `"1000"`.

The second one is that you don't have enough room for the dollar sign at the end. What you need is this:

```
// 6 characters: '1', '0', '0', '0', '$' and the terminating NUL
char word[6] = "1000";
strcat(word, "$");
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you are trying to concatenate to a literal string. Literal strings are constant and can not be changed.

You need to create the "destination" as an array instead, containing enough characters to fit your concatenation:

```
char word[16] = "1000";
```

The number 16 in the array above I picked arbitrary. It has to be at least big enough to fit the string you put in it, plus the length of the string you concatenate, plus the terminating `'\0'` character.

Comment: So, I can't use char* as a destination, right? Do I have to use the array?

Comment: @DarkCoffee That's not the point - declaring a pointer as `char *` doesn't magically make the underlying memory writable, it is still `const char *` (more precisely, `const char[]`). If you had used the `-Wall` compiler flag, you would have gotten a warning.

Comment: @H2CO3 if the char* come as a function parameter, do I have to translate it in a array?

Comment: @DarkCoffee No, you don't. You originally **pass in an array to the function** instead.

Comment: @H2CO3 ok, but if I have that char* defined, and I have to use it

Comment: @H2CO3 also if I use realloc?

Comment: @DarkCoffee You can't use `realloc` on something you have allocated using either `malloc`, `calloc` or an earlier `realloc`. In other words, you can't reallocate an arbitrary pointer.

Comment: @DarkCoffee In my last comment, I of course meant that you can't use `realloc` on something you **haven't** allocated explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong this should work:

```
char word[255] = "1000"; //Creating an array with 255 elements
const char dollar = '$'; //dollar is a single constant character '$'
word[4] = dollar; //the fourth element of the array, right after the 1000, becomes $

printf("%s", word);
```

Answer (score 0):

make it an array of chars.

```
char example[100];
strcat (example,"$");
```